# How to shuffle nested array with useState

Tags: javascript, react-native, lodash

I'm making a Quiz app in react native and I want to **shuffle the order of questions** *each time someone picks the quiz*. I was thinking about using **shuffle** from **lodash** but I'm not totally sure how to do for nested array.

```
const getTest = async () => {

     try {
        const response = await fetch('https://tgryl.pl/quiz/test/'.concat(route.params.testId));
        const json = await response.json();
        setData(json);
     }
     catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
     } 
}
```

I was thinking about something like `setData(_.shuffle(data.tasks))` ?? I have no idea

The JSON looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently the array to be shuffled is stored in the `tasks` property of the response object, so you should shuffle that array and assign it back to that property:

```
json.tasks = _.shuffle(json.tasks);
setData(json);
```

Even though this mutates an object and then passes it to `setData` (which presumably calls `setState`/`useState`, and such mutation is usually a code smell), this is not an issue here, as this object was never used before for the state.

Unrelated, but I would not call that variable `json`. It is a JavaScript object. JSON is the term for the text format that the `json()` method retrieves from the request and converts to the object/array.

Use a name that describes the content, like `quiz`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have nested arrays, you have arrays inside of an object. That's the response data structure you're receiving.

I think this is a fun question, so here I implemented an alternative way of shuffling the questions array.

### Logic

Do a loop through all the questions and inside of it:

1. Generate a random index between 0 and the length of the questions array.
2. Use `pop()` to remove the last element of the array and return it to the `Q` variable.
3. Use `splice()` to add question `Q` to the random index generated.

```js
const arr1 = [];
const arr2 = [
        {question: 'asd asd 1', answer: 'bla 1', duration: 10},
        {question: 'asd asd 2', answer: 'bla 2', duration: 20},
        {question: 'asd asd 3', answer: 'bla 3', duration: 15},
        {question: 'asd asd 4', answer: 'bla 4', duration: 30}
      ];
const arr3 = [];

const responseObject = {
  arr1,
  arr2,
  arr3
};
      
let questions = responseObject.arr2;

for(const question of questions){
  let randIndex = Math.round(Math.random()*(questions.length - 1));
  let Q = questions.pop(); 
  questions.splice(randIndex, 0, Q);
}

console.log(questions)
```